# When I Run My app it show Java Run time exception in android (want marker cluster in android map)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-mapview, android-maps, android-maps-v2

[image]here is my whole code

login is successful but after login it wouldn't show the map and clustering on it

so please help me

.......................................................login.java........................
    package com.vaib.login;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity{
     EditText edtemail,edtPassword;
        Button btnLogin;
        String strUsername,strPassword;

      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);
            edtemail = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edt_email);
            edtPassword = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edt_passwrd);
            btnLogin = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    strUsername = edtemail.getText().toString().trim();
                    strPassword = edtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                    if(strUsername.equals("needin@gmail.com") && strPassword.equals("needin123"))
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LoginSuccess.class).putExtra("usr",strUsername));
                     else 
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
            // Listening to register new account link
            registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Switching to Register screen
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
}
.............................registeractivity.java.........................................
package com.vaib.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);
        TextView loginScreen=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
        loginScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View args0) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

..................................loginSuccess.java.....................................

```
package com.vaib.login;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.Window;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.ivb.needin.MarkersClusterizer;

public class LoginSuccess extends FragmentActivity {

    private ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();
    private Bitmap markerImage;
    private float oldZoom = 0;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private static final int INTERVAL = 25;
    private LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusters;
    private final double initLat1 = 40.462740;
    private final double initLng1 = 30.039572;
    private final double initLat2 = 48.462740;
    private final double initLng2 = 35.039572;
    private static final int MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL = 11;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         markerImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            setContentView(R.layout.second);

            map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            LatLng position = new LatLng(initLat2, initLng2);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL));
            map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                    if (cameraPosition.zoom != oldZoom) {
                        try {
                            clusters = MarkersClusterizer.clusterMarkers(map, markers, INTERVAL);
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    oldZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;
                }
            });
            createMarkers(map);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        /**
         * Markers generation
         *
         * @param map target instance of {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap}
         */
        private void createMarkers(GoogleMap map) {
            double initLat;
            double initLng;

            initLat = initLat1;
            initLng = initLng1;
            for (float i = 0; i < 2; i += 0.2) {
                LatLng pos = new LatLng(initLat + i, initLng + i);
                markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerImage)));
            }

            initLat = initLat2;
            initLng = initLng2;
            for (float i = 0; i < 2; i += 0.2) {
                LatLng pos = new LatLng(initLat + i, initLng);
                markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerImage)));
            }
            for (float i = 0; i < 2; i += 0.2) {
                LatLng pos = new LatLng(initLat, initLng + i);
                markers.add(new MarkerOptions().position(pos).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerImage)));
            }

        }
}
package com.vaib.needin;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

/**
 * Utility class for clustering markers.
 * Add it to your project
 */
public class MarkersClusterizer {
    private static GoogleMap map;
    private static int interval;
    private static final int DEFAULT_INTERVAL = 25;

    /**
     * This method will clusterize markers and draw it on the given map instance.
     * Used default value for interval
     *
     * @param googleMap target {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap} instance
     * @param markers   list of all {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions}
     * @return map of clusters. You can use it to find all markers in given cluster.
     */
    public static LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusterMarkers(GoogleMap googleMap, ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return clusterMarkers(googleMap, markers, DEFAULT_INTERVAL);
    }

    /**
     * This method will clusterize markers and draw it on the given map instance
     *
     * @param googleMap target {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap} instance
     * @param markers   list of all {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions}
     * @param i         interval between two markers (in pixels)
     * @return map of clusters. You can use it to find all markers in given cluster.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusterMarkers(GoogleMap googleMap, ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markers, int i) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        map = googleMap;
        interval = i;
        Projection projection = map.getProjection();
        LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point> points = new LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point>();
        for (MarkerOptions markerOptions : markers) {
            points.put(markerOptions, projection.toScreenLocation(markerOptions.getPosition()));
            markerOptions.title("");
        }
        map.clear();

        CheckMarkersTask checkMarkersTask = new CheckMarkersTask();
        checkMarkersTask.execute(points);
        return checkMarkersTask.get();
    }

    private static class CheckMarkersTask extends AsyncTask<LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point>, Void, LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>>> {

        private double findDistance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
            return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
        }

        @Override
        protected LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> doInBackground(LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point>... params) {
            LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusters = new LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>>();
            LinkedHashMap<MarkerOptions, Point> points = params[0];
            for (MarkerOptions markerOptions : points.keySet()) { //go thru all markers
                Point point = points.get(markerOptions);
                double minDistance = -1; //Currently found min distance. This need for finding nearest point.
                Point nearestPoint = null; //Currently found nearest point
                double currentDistance;
                for (Point existingPoint : clusters.keySet()) {  //try to find existing cluster for current marker
                    currentDistance = findDistance(point.x, point.y, existingPoint.x, existingPoint.y);
                    if ((currentDistance <= interval) && ((currentDistance < minDistance) || (minDistance == -1))) {
                        minDistance = currentDistance;
                        nearestPoint = existingPoint;
                    }
                }

                if (nearestPoint != null) {
                    clusters.get(nearestPoint).add(markerOptions);
                } else {
                    ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markersForPoint = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();
                    markersForPoint.add(markerOptions);
                    clusters.put(point, markersForPoint);
                }
            }
            return clusters;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LinkedHashMap<Point, ArrayList<MarkerOptions>> clusters) {
            for (Point point : clusters.keySet()) {
                ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markersForPoint = clusters.get(point);
                MarkerOptions mainMarker = markersForPoint.get(0);
                int clusterSize = markersForPoint.size();
                if (clusterSize > 1) {
                    mainMarker.title(Integer.toString(clusterSize));
                }

                map.addMarker(mainMarker);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...................activity_main.xml......................................................

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
.....................second.xml..............................................
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginSuccess" >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip" >
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showmsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
                  </TextView>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
..............................register.xml............................................
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/header_gradient"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="5dip" >
                <ImageView android:src="@drawable/logo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"/>
</LinearLayout>        
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="10dip"
          android:layout_below="@id/header">
     <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Full Name"/>
          <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_fullname" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
           <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Email"/>
          <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_email" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"/>
          <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#372c24"
                android:text="Password"/>
          <EditText android:id="@+id/reg_password" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"/>
          <!-- Register Button -->      
          <Button android:id="@+id/btnRegister" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:text="Register New Account"/>
          <!-- Link to Login Screen -->
          <TextView android:id="@+id/link_to_login" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                android:text="Already has account! Login here"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="20dip"
                android:textColor="#025f7c"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

.............................login.xml...............................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/header_gradient" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/logo1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_email"
                android:layout_width="209dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter Email Address"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:typeface="normal" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"
                android:textColor="#372c24" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_passwrd"
                android:layout_width="209dp"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Enter password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:typeface="normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="133dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                android:background="#acd28a"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dip"
                android:text="Login" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Need an account?sign up"
                android:textColor="#0b84aa"
                android:textSize="20dip" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

.........................androidmanifest........................................

```
    <permission
        android:name="com.ivb.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.ivb.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ivb.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ivb.login.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="Register New Account" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ivb.login.LoginSuccess" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDWqmGeyGElk2elMGyb9Xe5mJCJ9njZtiI" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
            />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here i have given my whole code i want to show marker clusterer in this plz someone tell me it will not go to loginSucess.java

i am newbie at this and i am stuck on this problem from 2 weeks

thanxs[image]

Comment: Check  line 46 in your LoginSucess-Class. You get a null-pointer exception there.

Comment: @mayu it means it didn't find the map Id

Comment: did u tried to change the android:name in your second.xml. Because your are using the support libary, you have to use the SupportMapFragment.

Comment: @mayu i have already done this in second.xml

Answer (score 1):

You need to change in your xml file from

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

because in java class you are using ***SupportMapFragment*** also your minimu SDK version is 8.